# Use AJAX to update django if-else template

Tags: ajax, django, django-templates

In template I have:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% if item.public is True%}
    <a href="{% url 'motifapp:article_public_edit' article.id %}">
      show icon1
    </a>
    {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'motifapp:article_public_edit' article.id %}">
      show icon2
    </a>
    {% endif %}
{endfor}
```

I use ajax to handle the request here:

```
$(anchor).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href')
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: href,
            data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),},
            success: function (response) {
               //refresh a div ? 
            }
        });
    });
```

Ajax handle the post, and in view it reverse a boolean value 'public'.
Question is, how do I update the template? I can pass the opposite icons and value, but it seems very redundant. Is there a way just to refresh that div with anchor and let the if else statement takes care of what's showing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are 99% close to answer your own question.

First, you you must wrap the `{% for %}` in a div and save it as a separate file, say:

```
<!-- injection.html -->

<div id="some-id>
    {% for item in items %}
        same code here
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Now in your main template you should `include` that file like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    {% include 'templates/injection.html' %}
</div>
```

Now, once you make an AJAX request to your `views` function then this view should `render` that div (which is a separate html file) **but** with a different `items` value. Like this:

```
# views.py

def article_public_edit(request, id):
    if request.is_ajax():
        # new calculation of the items QuerySet
        # depending on the data passed through the $.ajax
        return render(request, 'injection.html', locals())
```

Finally, you can do this inside the `$.ajax()` `success` function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: href,
    data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),},
    success: function (response) {
         // replace the inside of #wrapper div with the injection.html (that has the new items values)
         $("#wrapper").replaceWith(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Works beautifully. One extra question, when I render that template in my edit function in view, in stead of copying all the code to regenerate whatever necessary to get locals(), is there anyway I can just call the original function to do that ?   Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *call the original function*? The meaning of the AJAX call is to make some recalculations and return a partial HTML or JSON data to the client (browser). If you mean to have some data persistent (whether its a `GET`, `POST`, or `AJAX` method) then put that data after the `def article_edit():` That way you'll always have them available.

Comment: in views.py, the page was originally render by function_A. Now this public_edit and ajax function change part of that page, can I somehow call function A at the end of public_edit to reload the content instead of copy bunch of code from function A to regenerate the content?

Comment: By function_A, you mean a `view` that takes a `request` as an argument? If yes, then why not include everything in the `function_A` view and inside there have the proper conditionals (`if request.method == 'POST'` or `if request.is_ajax()`)?

Answer (score 1):

With ajax calls there is no way the Django template tags will be re-evaluated. They only get evaluated on initial page load.

I think the best way to go is to have the ajax view return the boolean value and then set the image in your front-end code depending on that value.

Comment: guess this is the only way then ... ouch. Thanks for the explanation